# Is there a term for two distance metrics that give the same ordering?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In order to calculate and sort things by distance from each other in a computer program I need to find an easy and fast distance metric to calculate. I can probably find one myself. However, first I need to know a term I can use to search for this stuff online. I want a term for a measurement of distance that can be totally different from the Euclidean metric but that has the same ordering as the Euclidean metric. For example, the metric `r = Δx² + Δy² + Δz²` is fine (notice that there is no square root.)

To be more precise, I want a term for two metrics d₁ and d₂ such that d₁(a, x) < d₁(a, y) ⟺
d₂(a, x) < d₂(a, y) for any a, x and y.

Comment: Are you saying two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ such that $\|x\|_1 < \|y\|_1 \iff \|x\|_2 < \|y\|_2$ for all $x, y$?

Comment: Using the term metric is confusing because a metric is a function on pairs and so there is no way to use that to define an ordering on the elements

Comment: @muzzlator That sounds right.

Comment: He must mean norms, because "$r = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}$" doesn't look like a metric.

Comment: @muzzlator One of the points is a constant.